# How do I manually lookup a route in the RouteTable MVC.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a String inside the action of one of my controllers that represents a Referring URL. The current request's route data is not what I'm looking for (because it is being called from the script tag inside another view).

I want to find the Action and Controller for the referring Url.

Is there some way can I manually use a string like "/Product/23" to find the controller and action the string as a url would produce?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to use the MVC methods I got this to work.

```
            Uri returnUri = new Uri(returnUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            if (!returnUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
            {
                returnUri = new Uri("http://localhost" + returnUrl); // localhost used just to get absolute URL
            }
            HttpContextWrapper httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(
                new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(String.Empty, returnUri.AbsoluteUri, String.Empty), new HttpResponse(TextWriter.Null))
                );
            RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);
```